# How to escape script tag within iframe src?

Tags: javascript, iframe, code-injection, html-escape-characters

I'm trying to inject javascript file via iframe tag as so -

```
myElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<iframe class="x" style="y" src="javascript: \'<script src=\'/path/path/name.js\'><\/script>\'"></iframe>');
```

but I keep getting the folowing error message -
'' - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string

how to write it down correctly?

Comment: Use `srcdoc` not `src` to insert html.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the path to your src attribute and the content should load within your iframe

Example:

```js
const a = document.getElementById('myElement');
a.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', 
`<iframe class="x" style="y" src='/path/path/name.js'></iframe>`);
```

```html
<div id="myElement">
  element
</div>
```